# Android EditText value to integer

Tags: android, string, integer, android-edittext

I am creating a mortgage calculator android program and I was trying to figure out how to get the EditText value (comes back as an Editable) to convert to an integer so I can use those integers in the calculation of the mortgage.  I know that there is a toString() method.  Would that be the way to go and then try to convert it from a String to an integer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Integer i = Integer.valueOf(String s);
```

You should also configure the EditText to only accept integer values.