# How to convert String taken from a TextField view to an int

Tags: java, android, string, int

I have a `TextField` in a layout and I would like to retrieve it and convert it to an integer to put it in my database. I have used the following code but it keeps giving me some exception

```
EditText agefield = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.agefield);             
int age = Integer.parseInt(agefield.getText().toString());
```

Comment: Java and XML for android

Comment: It may be throwing `NullPointerException` or`NumberFormatException`. Just check incase your edittext value is really not empty or is a number !.

Answer (score 3):

if Java this line

```
int age = Integer.parseInt(agefield.getText().toString());
```

can be re-written as

```
int age = Integer.parseInt(agefield.getText());
```

Comment: not sure why you say so, however, what is the exception you are getting , also have you tried changing the code to what I suggested and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

Hi to achieve that in android; your exact question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4197356/android-edittext-value-to-integer).

In addition I will advise that you double check to verify that you have called the
setContentView(R.layout.main) for the activity concerned i.e ensure that xml file containing the agefield edittext has been set to the contentview before attempting to evoke EditText agefield = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.agefield). If it has not then you will get a null pointer because your edittext field will be null. After confirming that ensure that the value in the edittext is a valid number and its not empty.

I think the setContentView is the problem because i had a similar experience recently.

Feel free to mark as the answer if this answers your question.
Hope this helps, good luck!