# Android: How to Convert a number in a Buttons text to integer?

Tags: java, android, string

I'm making a simple dice rolling app as a way to learn some basics about Android Studio.

The method called `onClick` is shown below:

```
public void setSide(View v){
    Button b = (Button)v;
    sides = Integer.getInteger(b.getText().toString(),-1);
}
```

It seems to be passing -1 to `sides` no matter what, and all the buttons calling this method have only numbers in their strings (ex: "2", "20", "100", etc). Is there a way to fix this?

EDIT: I should probably explain that `sides` is local, and is used in another method, `doRoll` which is called the the Click of another button. This method sets the text of a textview to `roll(sides)`, a method which returns a number from 1-`sides` if `sides > 1`, otherwise it returns -999. I have `sides` initialized to 20, and when I press the `rollBtn` before anything else, it works fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android EditText value to integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4197356/android-edittext-value-to-integer)

Comment: check with one codition if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(b.getText().toString()){sides = Integer.getInteger(b.getText().toString());} else{ sides = -1;}

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6835980/android-converting-string-to-int

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

`sides = Integer.parseInt(b.getText().toString());`

Comment: This works, but I'm still getting an error... I think it may be in the displaying of the roll. It warned me when I tried to use `(Integer)(roll(sides)).toString()`, and I'm not sure how to use the `String.format(params)` method. Could you tell me how to make it so the `format()` method prints just an integer?

Comment: the popup Android Studio gives me one with `String locale, Object... args` and another with `String format, String locale, Object... args` I'm not sure which one to use

Comment: Can you explain more clearly what and in what form you want to format

Comment: I just want to put an int in a TextView. When I tried to use the `Integer.toString()` method, I got a warning saying not to do so, and to use the `String.format()` method instead, but I'm not sure how to use it, as I've never worked with it before.

Comment: for that purpose use String.valueOf() method

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
sides = Integer.parseInt(b.getText().toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know:

```
public void setSide(View v){
Button b = (Button)v;
sides = Integer.parseInt(b.getText().toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check with only one condition :-

```
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(b.getText().toString())){
    sides = Integer.getInteger(b.getText().toString());
} else {
    sides = -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sides = Integer.parseInt(button.getText().toString());
```

it works for me